# Access a non-MonoBehaviour script from another script (Unity)

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project and i would like to access a non MonoBehaviour script from another script. 
I can't use GetComponent cause the script isn't MonoBehabiour, is there a solution ? 
Here is some code to help you understand :

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static float coolVar = 1.0f;
            private string someVar; // EDIT : I need to access this var too and AnotherClass.someVar won't work obviously  



public class AnotherClass {
    // i want to be able to access coolVar and change her value
// i know i can do SomeClass.coolVar but i was looking for another way close to a GetComponent approach
```

My SomeClass class is full of static var i need to edit, i didn't implemented those variables and i can't modify them (i know it's bad practices).

Maybe the reflection is the best way :

```
typeof(SomeClasse).GetField(name).SetValue(null, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to include the script with the not MonoBehaviour class inside the Assets path of the project and you will be able to use it inside other behaviour class.
Take care of use only .NET 2.0 specifications in the external class and if u have used a namespace on it add the using in the behaviour script.

```
#External class 
namespace DefNamespace
{
public class ModelList
{
    private static List<GameObject> models;

    private ModelList ()
    {
    }

    public static List<GameObject> Models{
        get{
            if(models == null) models= new List<GameObject>();
            return models;
        }set{
            models=value;
        }
    }

}
}
```

And then in a MonoBehaviour or another class:

```
#Behaviour
using DefNamespace;

public class DefBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    Start(){
        GameObject go=ModelList.Models[0];
    }
}
```